# BIRT upgrade from 2.6.2 to 4.2.2 resulted in "null" labels in report

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I am working on RCP product that was upgraded from eclipse 3.6.2 to eclipse 4.2.2. So the BIRT plugins are upgraded from 2.6.2 to 4.2.2. The product is used to create reports in PDF and word format using BIRT. Before upgrade it was working perfectly. But after upgrade, the report gets generated with correct data but the static labels are coming as "null" in header. 
For example: 
null: Actor
This should be Concept: Actor

I have never worked on BIRT reporting. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eclipse 4.2.2 is 10 releases out of date, and if I remember correctly was buggy. You should be targeting a newer release even if it doesn't fix this issue.

Comment: @greg-449 : Thank you for your reply. We are planning to upgrade to newer eclipse version but not immediately. Could you please let me know if you have any idea about any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't use Birt. But I don't think there is enough information here for anybody to help. Again don't waste time on 4.2 it also had performance issues.